# How to link this button to another route in Laravel Bacpack

Tags: laravel-backpack

So i have this view below :

[The button view that i want to route to another page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VKPGv.jpg)

Theres a button named **Go To Question** that i want to link to **edit-question** route. This is the code for the button.

```
[   // CustomHTML
                    'name'  => 'separator',
                    'type'  => 'custom_html',
                    'value' => '<a href="{{$this->crud->setEditView(`backpack::crud.question`,3);}}" 
                     target="_blank">Go to question ></a>'
                ],
```

Does anyone know how to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

You can easily link to a Backpack page using the `backpack_url()` helper instead of Laravel's standard `url()`. That will also add the admin prefix that you've set in your `config/backpack/base.php` (by default `admin`).

But take note that you *cannot* add a link to a particular view in Laravel. You should point to *a route*, that points to *a controller*, that loads *a view*. So your button should look more like this:

```php
[   // CustomHTML
                    'name'  => 'separator',
                    'type'  => 'custom_html',
                    'value' => '<a href="{{ backpack_url('question/3/edit') }}" 
                     target="_blank">Go to question ></a>'
                ],
```

This will point to the Questions CRUD route, which will load QuestionCrudController, which in its turn will load the edit view - assuming you do have that CRUD.